# Como evitar ataque de SQL Injection nessa consulta?

Tags: php, sql-injection

Nesse caso, estou passando o WHERE através da variável $where. O sistema pode sofrer SQL Injection? Como evita-lo nesse caso?

Por exemplo: `select nome from usuario where $where;`

```
$where = "cod = 10";

public static function getUsuario($where){
    return Usuario::all(array(     
        'select' => 'nome',
        'conditions' => array($where)
    ));
}
```

Comment: É algum framework? Ou um código seu?

Comment: To utilizando o PHP ActiveRecord + Smarty

Comment: Assim? Do pé para a mão sem ver mais código nenhum? Sim, estás a um passo de receber um SQL Injection. No entanto, se alguma das tuas frameworks usar `mysqli_*` **acho** que não. Pelo sim, pelo não, eu escapava esse input só para não ter surpresas ao fim do dia :)

Comment: Qual a vantagem "escapar" o input?

Comment: Escapar o input ajuda a garantir que os dados contidos em `$where` sejam dados mesmo, não código. Mas não sei se é "à prova de balas" (e de todo modo, se esses dados já estiverem sendo escapados escapar de novo vai provocar um duplo escape, o que é ruim). De onde está vindo o valor de `$where`? Do usuário?

Comment: De uma uma funcao que retorna o campo(nome) + o valor(que vem de um input).

Comment: A propósito, esse código aí é do ActiveRecord ou do Smarty (ou de ambos, se um foi construído em cima do outro). Teria alguma documentação para consultarmos? De fato, se a variável inclui um valor que veio do *browser*, esse valor tem de ser sanitizado (tanto na entrada - pra prevenir SQL Injection - quanto na saída - pra prevenir XSS [não aplicável no seu caso]). A documentação da framework deve ajudar a esclarecer essa primeira parte, se encontrá-la poste junto à pergunta, podemos ajudar a "decifrá-la" rsrs.

Comment: Eh um framework feito por um cara da equipe de desenvolvimento aqui. Ele eh um mix de várias coisa rsrs

Comment: O valor do where vem de um return "nome + valor", onde valor é o valor do input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se pode ocorrer ou não eu não sei responder, vai depender da *framework* utilizada. Mas evitar deve ser bem mais fácil, é só **validar** o campo, ver se seu formato corresponde àquilo que você espera dele (e que portanto não vai conter código malicioso, ou qualquer código que seja, e sim *dados*).

Seu campo `$where` é composto da concatenação de `$nome` e `$valor`, certo? Um nome normalmente é composto de letras, números e *underscore* (`_`). Um valor normalmente é composto de dígitos, talvez um menos na frente e talvez um ponto. E eu estou supondo que você os concatena usando um `=`, certo? Então:

1. Valide o `$nome` como sendo um nome; *mesmo que* ele venha do seu próprio código (não custa nada, fica como "teste de sanidade":

   ```
   if (preg_match("/^\w+$/", $nome)) {
       ...
   } else {
       /* Não continue! Reporte um erro! */
   }
   ```
2. Valide o `$valor` como sendo um número; o exemplo abaixo é para um decimal simples, em formato brasileiro/europeu (não americano), ajuste-o de acordo com suas necessidades:

   ```
   if (preg_match("/^-?\d+(\.\d{3})*(\,\d+)?$/", $valor)) {
       ...
   } else {
       /* Não continue! Reporte um erro! */
   }
   ```
3. Concatene `$nome` e `$valor`; [não use aspas em volta do número](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2078942/520779):

   ```
   $condicao = $nome . " = " . $valor
   ```
4. Alternativamente, se o `$valor` é uma string que pode conter `-` e `/`, além de letras, números e underscore (e *só isso*):

   ```
   if (preg_match("/^(\w|\/|-)+$/", $valor)) {
   ```

   E para concatenar:

   ```
   $condicao = $nome . " = '" . $valor . "'"
   ```

   No caso, sabemos que nem `-` nem `/` quando **dentro de uma string** são suficientes para causar problemas (uma aspa ou talvez uma `\` seriam), e como não está sendo usado um `LIKE` (caso em que `_` seria um problema), então deve ser seguro.

Etc. Se `$nome` possui um valor correto, `$valor` possui um valor correto, a concatenação possui a sintaxe correta, e *todos* os elementos do seu array `$where` foram montados da forma correta, então não há por onde uma Injeção de SQL ocorrer. Tenham os componentes sido "escapados" ou não, não faz diferença, pois o escape os deixará inalterados.

Validar os valores é uma alternativa melhor do que aceitar qualquer formato de entrada e tentar sanitizá-la. Inclusive, sanitizar algo que não se sabe o que é é temerário (vai que você "escapou" corretamente na hora de colocar no banco, mas ao tirar dele - e "desescapá-lo" - você o incluiu no HTML de resposta, sem nenhuma checagem, o resultado será um XSS ou similar...). Use essa estratégia sempre que o formato dos dados de entrada for previsível e bem definido, e só terá de se preocupar com os campos mais abertos (texto livre, por exemplo).

Comment: meu valor pode ser string e inteiro, e com conter "-" e "/"...

Comment: @PauloCosta Atualizei a resposta com um exemplo. Que eu saiba, nenhum desses caracteres pode causar problemas, desde que o valor esteja dentro das aspas, como se espera de uma string (se estivesse fora, um `--` poderia causar problemas). Como falei no final, essa resposta só vale para quando o campo é fechado (i.e. possui um formato rígido), se o mesmo fosse aberto (qualquer coisa vale) então é mais complicado. O ideal mesmo seria usar *queries parametrizadas*, mas como não sabemos se sua framework suporta isso ou não (pelo "jeitão" do seu código eu diria que não) esse é o meio mais garantido.

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta! Obrigadao

Comment: Se eu quiser q minha String tenha "." e " _ "??

Comment: @PauloCosta `_` já é contemplado pelo `\w`. O `.` precisa ser escapado com `\ ` (ele é um caractere especial na regex). O resultado então é: `/^(\w|\/|-|\.)+$/`

Answer (score 0):

Esse código só tem problemas de SQL injection se esse parâmetro vier de input do user.

Se esse where não vem do browser / utilizador, não tem problema.

Caso seja user input, deve sempre se usado escape no php, ou então parâmetros nos queries, nunca input directo.